# COMO COLOCAR UN TITULO ANTES DE UN LISTVIEW - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy tratando de poner un Titulo antes de colocar un ListView, el titulo tiene como dato la hora de salida de un chofer y el ListView muestra el detalle de dirección y la hora que tiene que llegar, todo los datos están en una sola Colección en FireBase.

-he intentado hacer con Column,table,DataTable como resultado me muestra de esta manera:

HoraSalida 
Direccion 
HoraLlegada

HoraSalida
Direccion
HoraLlegada

HoraSalida
Direccion
HoraLlegada

y asi sucecivamente, **y lo que quiero es asi:**

HoraSalida

Direccion
HoraLlegada

Direccion
HoraLlegada

Direccion
HoraLlegada

**que tenga la hora de salida como titulo y luego el detalle, muchas gracias por su tiempo.**

```
Widget _crearListaPronostico(){
// FIXME: corregir problema de visualizacion de salida
return FutureBuilder<List<PronosticoModel>>(
  future: pronostico(prefs.cedula, estado),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PronosticoModel>> snapshot){

    if(!snapshot.hasData){return Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator());}
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
      itemBuilder: (contex, i){
        String direccion= snapshot.data[i].nombreGeoPunto;
        String horaLlegar= 'Llegar:  '+ hourFormat.format(DateTime.parse(snapshot.data[i].fechaHoraPronostico));
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(direccion),
          subtitle: Text(horaLlegar)
        );
      },  
    );
   
  }
 );
}
```

Comment: porqué tienes 2 futurebuilder con lo mismo ? future: pronostico(prefs.cedula, estado),

Comment: ya lo actualice, llegue ahi por estar probando con column en uno obtenia solo la horaSalida y en el otro el detalle pero no funciona, al momento de traer el detalle me da un error de dimension del listview, alguna solución o recomendación para obtener lo que busco??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas un `Column` con el título que deseas y el `ListView` pero encima tiene que tener el widget `Expanded` para que se pueda expandir en todo el contenido que sobra, te preparé un ejemplo:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Hora Salida',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemCount: 20,
              separatorBuilder: (_, __) => Divider(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('Dirección'),
                subtitle: Text('Hora Llegada'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta, pero esta con datos estáticos como seria con mi future que trae datos?

Comment: En lugar del ListView.separeted , ahí coloca : _crearListaPronostico

Comment: gracias Diego.!

Comment: suscribete al canal que tenemos en youtube donde hablamos de dart y flutter :https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Comment: ya vengo siguiendo al canal y también a ti.